# Regex to capture a part of a word

Tags: c#, regex

```
my text has $1 per Lap to someone.
```

I have above kind of text.I need to pick the `per Lap` part which is come after the $1 amount.Can you tell me how to do that ?

I can pick a $ part using `new Regex(@"\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?").Match(s.Comment1).Groups[0].ToString()`.But I need the `per Lap` part ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need the first two words that follow an amount?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight exactly :)

Comment: Words have boundaries... I assume you've also tried to find something like https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+regex+word to learn how to detect word - possibly should include that research into the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use lookbehind for that, like this:

```
(?<=\$\d+\s*)(\w+\s*\w+)
```

The `(?<=...)` portion in front of an expression means "when preceded by...". This part of the expression must be matched, but it is ignored in the final result.

[Simplified demo](https://regex101.com/r/eI1bX3/2) (unlike C#'s regex engine, the engine used in the demo does not support variable-length lookbehinds, so I transformed the expression a little to illustrate the point).

Comment: Can I have this help too ? That is how can I pick the 2 words after $ amount and it must contain `per` as the first word.E.g.  $1 to Lap - this one should not pick.$1 per Lap - This is the correct one.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sampath Replace first `\w+` with `per`, and move it into the lookbehind, because it's going to stay the same: `(?<=\$\d+\s*per+\s*)(\w+)`

Comment: It doesn't pick the $1 to Lap scenario.Which is correct.But on other scenario where it doesn't show the `per` part. i.e it shows `Lap` only.So can I have `per Lap` ?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sampath Yes - I moved it into the lookbehind, but you can certainly move it back into the capturing part of the expression: `(?<=\$\d+\s*)(per\s*\w+)`

Comment: When I use this `my text has $0.05 per Lap to someone.`,it doesn't show the `per Lap` part.Can you tell me how to pick that scenario also.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sampath replace `\d+` with `[\d.]+` to allow for dots to be mixed with the numbers. If you want to pick up European-style separators as well, use `[\d.,]+`

Comment: Like this `(?<=\$[\d.]+\s*)(per\s*\w+)` ?

Comment: @Sampath Yes, that's it.

Comment: @Sampath regex101 uses a different regex engine. C#'s engine allows variable-size lookbehind expressions, while the one used by the site (PHP) requires lookbehings to be of fixed length. That's why I simplified my demo to remove `+` after `\d` and also `*` after `\s`.

Comment: Yes.You're right.It's working fine with .Net.Thanks a lot for your continues support. Keep up the Great work :)

Answer (score 1):

### [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oG6bG1/1)

```
^.*\$\d+\s+(\w+\s+\w+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ATdyW9GKUW-Pw5Ue)